# Как вернуть коммиты после Revert?

Tags: git

Ситуация такая:
Eсть 2 ветки - master и dev. С dev создал pull request, его подтвердили, а позже сделали revert. Внес некоторые изменения, а теперь, при создании pull request, прошлых коммитов нет, которые входили в прошлый pull request, в самой ветки dev они есть, но в список реквеста не попадают. Могу ли я добавить в новый реквест те старые коммиты?

Answer (score 0):

Тут стоит понять, что revert - создание нового коммита

Так что ваши коммиты уже есть в мастере и повторно добавить их в пулл реквест не получится, но можно смержить в дев мастер ветку и сделать реверт коммита реверта
(это при условии, что мы не хотим переписывать историю коммитов)